# How use UIDefault for create new look and feel for swing

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

I'm developing a new look and feel for Java; this look and feel imports the Material-style.

I had used the UIDefault for import the change inside the look and feel, so now I must uninstall the look and feel and I have a problem with this operation.

The look and feel con not removed correctly, now I've used for all operation the UIDefault map and I think this is an error because my constant override the old constant and when I go to remove my look and feel. the new look and feel don't override my constant

This is how I'm using the UIDefault

```java
@Override
    protected void initComponentDefaults(UIDefaults table) {
        super.initComponentDefaults(table);

        table.put("Button.highlight", MaterialColors.GRAY_400);
        table.put("Button.opaque", false);
        table.put("Button.border", BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(7, 17, 7, 17));
        table.put("Button.background", MaterialColors.GRAY_200);
        table.put("Button.foreground", MaterialColors.COSMO_BLACK);
        table.put("Button.disabledBackground", MaterialColors.COSMO_DARK_GRAY);
        table.put("Button.disabledForeground", MaterialColors.BLACK);
        table.put("Button[Default].background", MaterialColors.LIGHT_BLUE_500);
        table.put("Button[Default].foreground", Color.WHITE);
        table.put("Button.font", MaterialFontFactory.getInstance().getFont(MaterialFontFactory.BOLD));
        //table.put("Button[Default].mouseHoverColor", MaterialColors.LIGHT_BLUE_200);
        table.put("Button.mouseHoverColor", MaterialColors.GRAY_500);
        table.put("Button.mouseHoverEnable", true);
        table.put("Button.focusable", true);
        table.put("Button[focus].color", MaterialColors.GRAY_900);
        table.put("Button.disabledText", MaterialColors.GRAY_600);

        table.put("CheckBox.font", MaterialFontFactory.getInstance().getFont(MaterialFontFactory.BOLD));
        table.put("CheckBox.background", MaterialColors.WHITE);
        table.put("CheckBox.foreground", MaterialColors.BLACK);
        table.put("CheckBox.disabledText", MaterialColors.COSMO_STRONG_GRAY);
        table.put("CheckBox.icon", new ImageIcon(MaterialImageFactory.getInstance().getImage(MaterialImageFactory.UNCHECKED_BLACK_BOX)));
        table.put("CheckBox.selectedIcon", new ImageIcon(MaterialImageFactory.getInstance().getImage(MaterialImageFactory.CHECKED_BLACK_BOX)));

        table.put("ComboBox.font", MaterialFontFactory.getInstance().getFont(MaterialFontFactory.REGULAR));
        table.put("ComboBox.background", MaterialColors.WHITE);
        table.put("ComboBox.foreground", MaterialColors.BLACK);
        table.put("ComboBox.border", MaterialBorders.roundedLineColorBorder(MaterialColors.COSMO_BLACK));
        table.put("ComboBox.borderItems", BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 2, 0, 1));
        table.put("ComboBox.buttonBackground", MaterialColors.WHITE);
        table.put("ComboBox[button].border", BorderFactory.createLineBorder(MaterialColors.WHITE));
        table.put("ComboBox.disabledBackground", MaterialColors.WHITE);
        table.put("ComboBox.disabledForeground", MaterialColors.GRAY_900);
        table.put("ComboBox.selectionBackground", MaterialColors.WHITE);
        table.put("ComboBox.selectionForeground", Color.BLACK);
        table.put("ComboBox.selectedInDropDownBackground", MaterialColors.COSMO_LIGTH_BLUE);
        table.put("ComboBox.mouseHoverColor", MaterialColors.WHITE);
        table.put("ComboBox.unfocusColor", MaterialColors.COSMO_BLACK);
        table.put("ComboBox.focusColor", MaterialColors.LIGHT_BLUE_400);
        table.put("ComboBox.mouseHoverEnabled", false);

        table.put("Menu.font", MaterialFontFactory.getInstance().getFont(MaterialFontFactory.REGULAR));
        table.put("Menu.border", BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        table.put("Menu.background", Color.WHITE);
        table.put("Menu.foreground", Color.BLACK);
        table.put("Menu.opaque", true);
        table.put("Menu.selectionBackground", MaterialColors.GRAY_200);
        table.put("Menu.selectionForeground", MaterialColors.BLACK);
        table.put("Menu.disabledForeground", new Color(0, 0, 0, 100));
        table.put("Menu.menuPopupOffsetY", 3);
        table.put("Menu[MouseOver].enable", true); //TODO adding into master

        table.put("MenuBar.font", MaterialFontFactory.getInstance().getFont(MaterialFontFactory.BOLD));
        table.put("MenuBar.background", Color.WHITE);
        table.put("MenuBar.border", MaterialBorders.LIGHT_SHADOW_BORDER);
        table.put("MenuBar.foreground", MaterialColors.BLACK);

        table.put("MenuItem.disabledForeground", new Color(0, 0, 0, 100));
        table.put("MenuItem.selectionBackground", MaterialColors.GRAY_200);
        table.put("MenuItem.selectionForeground", Color.BLACK);
        table.put("MenuItem.font", MaterialFontFactory.getInstance().getFont(MaterialFontFactory.MEDIUM));
        table.put("MenuItem.background", Color.WHITE);
        table.put("MenuItem.foreground", Color.BLACK);
        table.put("MenuItem.border", BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 0, 5, 0));
    }
```

This is my app with my look and feel
[image]

This is my app when changing the look and feel
[image]

This is the code for changing the look and feel

```java
public class DemoGUITest extends JFrame {

    static {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new MaterialLookAndFeel());
            JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static final DemoGUITest SINGLETON = new DemoGUITest();


    public void reloadUI(){
        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this);
    }

    public void changeThemeWith(BasicLookAndFeel lookAndFeel){
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(lookAndFeel);
            this.reloadUI();
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SINGLETON.initComponent();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is a minimal example

Class main

```java
import com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel;
import mdlaf.utils.MaterialColors;
import mdlaf.utils.MaterialFontFactory;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource;
import javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

/**
 * @author https://github.com/vincenzopalazzo
 */
public class MaterialMain extends JFrame {

    public static MaterialMain SINGLETON = new MaterialMain();

    static {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new LookAndFeelTest());
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void init() {
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(file);
        this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        JButton changeTheme = new JButton();
        changeTheme.setAction(new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new GTKLookAndFeel());
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(SINGLETON);
            }
        });
        changeTheme.setText("Set GTK");

        panel.add(changeTheme);

        setTitle("Look and feel");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setSize(630, 360);

        add(panel);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SINGLETON.init();
            }
        });
    }

    public static class LookAndFeelTest extends MetalLookAndFeel{

        @Override
        protected void initClassDefaults(UIDefaults table) {
            super.initClassDefaults(table);
           table.put("MenuUI", MenuTestUI.class.getCanonicalName());
           table.put("ButtonUI", JButtonUI.class.getCanonicalName());
        }

        @Override
        protected void initComponentDefaults(UIDefaults table) {
            super.initComponentDefaults(table);

            //table.put("Menu.font", new FontUIResource(MaterialFontFactory.getInstance().getFont(MaterialFontFactory.REGULAR)));
            table.put("Menu.border", new BorderUIResource(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5)));
            table.put("Menu.background", (Color.ORANGE));
            table.put("Menu.foreground", (Color.BLACK));
            table.put("Menu.opaque", true);
            table.put("Menu.selectionBackground", new ColorUIResource(Color.YELLOW));
            table.put("Menu.selectionForeground", new ColorUIResource(Color.BLACK));
            table.put("Menu.disabledForeground", new ColorUIResource(new Color(0, 0, 0, 100)));
            table.put("Menu.menuPopupOffsetY", 3);

            //table.put("MenuBar.font", MaterialFontFactory.getInstance().getFont(MaterialFontFactory.BOLD));
            table.put("MenuBar.background", (Color.ORANGE));
            //table.put("MenuBar.border", MaterialBorders.LIGHT_SHADOW_BORDER);
            table.put("MenuBar.foreground", (Color.BLACK));

            table.put("Button.highlight", Color.ORANGE);
            table.put("Button.opaque", false);
            table.put("Button.border", BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(7, 17, 7, 17));
            table.put("Button.background", Color.ORANGE);
            table.put("Button.foreground", Color.BLACK);
            table.put("Button.focusable", true);
            table.put("Button[focus].color", Color.GREEN);
        }
    }
}
```

MenuUI

```java
import mdlaf.animation.MaterialUIMovement;
import mdlaf.components.menu.MaterialMenuUI;
import mdlaf.utils.MaterialManagerListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuUI;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 * @author https://github.com/vincenzopalazzo
 */
public class MenuTestUI extends BasicMenuUI {
    public static ComponentUI createUI (JComponent c) {
        return new MaterialMenuUI();
    }

    @Override
    public void installUI (JComponent c) {
        super.installUI (c);

        JMenu menu = (JMenu) c;
        menu.setFont (UIManager.getFont ("Menu.font"));
        menu.setBorder (UIManager.getBorder ("Menu.border"));
        menu.setBackground (UIManager.getColor ("Menu.background"));
        menu.setForeground (UIManager.getColor ("Menu.foreground"));
        menu.setOpaque (UIManager.getBoolean ("Menu.opaque"));
        c.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));


    }

    @Override
    public void uninstallUI(JComponent c) {

        menuItem.setFont (null);
        menuItem.setBackground (null);
        menuItem.setForeground (null);
        menuItem.setBorder (null);
        menuItem.setCursor(null);

        MaterialManagerListener.removeAllMaterialMouseListener(menuItem);

        super.uninstallUI(menuItem);
    }
}
```

ButtonUI

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonUI;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 * @author https://github.com/vincenzopalazzo
 */
public class JButtonUI extends BasicButtonUI {

    public static final String UI_KEY = "ButtonUI";

    public static ComponentUI createUI(final JComponent c) {
        return new JButtonUI();
    }

    private AbstractButton button;
    private Color foreground;
    private Color background;
    private Color disabledBackground;
    private Color disabledForeground;
    private Color defaultBackground;
    private Color defaultForeground;
    private Boolean isDefaultButton = null;

    @Override
    public void installUI(JComponent c) {
        super.installUI(c);

        AbstractButton button = (AbstractButton) c;
        button.setOpaque(UIManager.getBoolean("Button.opaque"));
        button.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("Button.border"));
        foreground = UIManager.getColor("Button.foreground");
        background = UIManager.getColor("Button.background");
        disabledBackground = UIManager.getColor("Button.disabledBackground");
        disabledForeground = UIManager.getColor("Button.disabledForeground");
        defaultBackground = UIManager.getColor("Button[Default].background");
        defaultForeground = UIManager.getColor("Button[Default].foreground");
        button.setBackground(background);
        button.setForeground(foreground);
        button.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        button.setFocusable(UIManager.getBoolean("Button.focusable"));

        this.button = button;
    }

    @Override
    public void uninstallUI(JComponent c) {
        super.uninstallUI(c);

        AbstractButton button = (AbstractButton) c;
        button.setBorder(null);
        foreground = null;
        background = null;
        disabledBackground = null;
        disabledForeground = null;
        defaultBackground = null;
        defaultForeground = null;
        button.setBackground(null);
        button.setForeground(null);
        button.setCursor(null);

    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
        JButton b = (JButton) c;
        if (b.isContentAreaFilled()) {
            paintBackground(g, b);
        }
        if (isDefaultButton == null && b.isEnabled()) {
            isDefaultButton = ((JButton) button).isDefaultButton();
            if (isDefaultButton) {
                paintStateButton(c, g);
            }
        }
        super.paint(g, c);
    }

    private void paintBackground(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
        Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g.setColor(c.getBackground());
        JButton b = (JButton) c;
        if (!UIManager.getBoolean("Button[border].toAll") && (button.getIcon() != null)) {
            g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, c.getWidth(), c.getHeight(), 7, 7);
        } else {
            g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, c.getWidth(), c.getHeight(), 7, 7);
            if (isDefaultButton != null && isDefaultButton) {
                g.setColor(UIManager.getColor("Button[Default].background"));
                if(UIManager.getBoolean("Button[Default].shadowEnable")){
                    paintShadow(g, button);
                }
                return;
            }

            if(UIManager.getBoolean("Button[border].enable")){
                paintBorderButton(graphics, b);
            }
        }

        paintStateButton(c, g);

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintFocus(Graphics g, AbstractButton b, Rectangle viewRect, Rectangle textRect, Rectangle iconRect) {
        // driveLine(g, (JButton) b);
        paintFocusRing(g, (JButton) b);
        //paintShadow(MaterialDrawingUtils.getAliasedGraphics(g), button);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
        super.update(g, c);
        //c.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintButtonPressed(Graphics g, AbstractButton b) {
        g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, b.getWidth(), b.getHeight(), 7, 7);
    }

    protected void paintFocusRing(Graphics g, JButton b) {
        Stroke dashed = new BasicStroke(1, BasicStroke.CAP_SQUARE, BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER, 10.0f, new float[]{0f, 3f}, 10.0f);
        //Stroke dashed = new BasicStroke(3, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL, 0, new float[]{9}, 0);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2.setStroke(dashed);
        if (isDefaultButton) {
            g2.setColor(UIManager.getColor("Button[Default][focus].color"));
        } else {
            g2.setColor(UIManager.getColor("Button[focus].color"));
        }

        g2.drawRoundRect(5, 5, b.getWidth() - 10, b.getHeight() - 10, 7, 7);

        g2.dispose();
    }

    protected void paintShadow(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
        int topOpacity = 80;
        int pixels = UIManager.getInt("Button[Default].shadowPixel");
        JButton b = (JButton) c;
        int valueRed = 255;
        int valueGreen = 255;
        int valueBlue = 255;
        for (int i = pixels; i >= 0; i--) {
            if(valueBlue > 70){
                valueRed -= 70;
                valueGreen -= 70;
                valueBlue -= 70;
            }else{
                valueBlue -= valueBlue;
                valueGreen -= valueGreen;
                valueRed -= valueRed;
            }

            Color result = new Color(valueRed, valueGreen, valueBlue, topOpacity);
            g.setColor(result);
            g.drawRoundRect(i, i, b.getWidth() - ((i * 2) + 1), b.getHeight() - ((i * 2) + 1), 7, 7);
        }

    }

    protected void paintBorderButton(Graphics2D graphics, JButton b) {
        graphics.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2f));

        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        int w = b.getWidth() - 1;
        int h = b.getHeight() - 1;
        int arc = 7;

        graphics.setColor(UIManager.getColor("Button[border].color"));
        graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, w, h, arc, arc);
    }

    protected void paintStateButton(JComponent component, Graphics graphics) {
        if (component == null || graphics == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input null");
        }
        JButton b = (JButton) component;
        if (b.isEnabled() && (isDefaultButton != null && isDefaultButton) && !b.isSelected()) {
            //MaterialManagerListener.removeAllMaterialMouseListener(b);
            //b.addMouseListener(MaterialUIMovement.getMovement(b, MaterialColors.LIGHT_BLUE_100));
            b.setBackground(defaultBackground);
            b.setForeground(defaultForeground);
            return;
        }
        if (!b.isEnabled()) {
            b.setBackground(disabledBackground);
            b.setForeground(disabledForeground);
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

But this code does not reproduced the problem even though I copied my code; a demo with the error is [here](https://github.com/vincenzopalazzo/material-ui-swing/blob/create_material_default_theme/src/test/java/integration/gui/mock/DemoGUITest.java)

I wanted to ask you if the problem is the one described above and especially if I used UIDefault badly

Comment: This question seems to lack a MCVE since it can't reproduce the problem. Second, we can't really tell *you* what the error is... you tell *us* what it is and we help you fix it. It's also unclear what you mean by "used UIDefault badly".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be an issue of your usage of L&F. All the resources, you put into the `UIManager` (except the primitives), must be the instances of `javax.swing.plaf.UIResource` intreface. Swing offers some predefined classes like `ColorUIResource`, `BorderUIResource`, `IconUIResource`, etc., that you can use in your code.

Why is it required? This interface tells the next Look-n-Feel that this setting can be changed when it applies its settings.

Code example:

```
table.put("OptionPane.warningDialog.titlePane.shadow", new ColorUIResource(MaterialColors.COSMO_STRONG_GRAY));
table.put("FormattedTextField.border", new BorderUIResource(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3, 5, 2, 5)));
table.put("List.font", new FontUIResource(MaterialFontFactory.getInstance().getFont(MaterialFontFactory.MEDIUM)));
```

Probably it would be better when your factories provide the resources in form of UIResource instances.

**IMPORTANT**
When my suggestion don't help you to solve your problems, please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can better understand what's wrong and also can debug your code to provide a solution that is reasonable for your case.

Comment: Thank so much for your help, I looked for created a look and fell per example but it did not reproduce the error, even though I copied and pasted the code, I also posted a demo that uses the real look and feel and left the link to the github repo (it's not the main branch)

Comment: Also, I have need to the line guide for the developer the look and feel, an example if in the UIDefault put the constant "Button.myPesonalConstan", this operation is correct? I can insert into UIDefault the personal constant? or I must create an LookAndFeelPesonalMap for used the personal constant ed in the UIDefault I have insert only constants shared with other look and feel?

Comment: 1) Sorry, but without to have a [mcve] it's not possible to help you. 2) Yes, you can put into UIDefault your own constants, that are required for your L&F only.

Comment: I could not reproduce the error with a minimal example but I created this post not to get fix the problem but to have a discussion on the good rules of the UIDefault, Now I’m gonna try to make your advice and see if I can make any changes. Thanks man

Comment: The problem was it, thanks so much man :) I will add the reference inside the readme of the project, thanks